# Open Camera/Gallery with Android Navigation Arch Component (JetPack)

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using the navigation arch component in my app and I have +/- under control the navigation between fragments and even with other activities in the same app.

But now I want to get a photo from the camera or from the gallery. The example to do it is pretty clear in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) without the navigation arch component. Basically you need these two methods `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`.

But I don't know what to do to with navigation arch component to have the same result. I've found this [article](https://medium.com/a-problem-like-maria/a-problem-like-navigation-part-2-63e46a565d4b) but the case is for activities in the same app, so it's not the same case.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488351/android-jetpack-navigation-library-and-onactivityresult Other ideas?

Comment: Add another activity "CameraActivity" to your internal nav graph and all that activity does is startActivityForResult and capture and package the result back into your app from the external. Good for analytics etc as well

Comment: Not bad workaround...

Comment: I've found this issue opened: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79672220

Comment: I think the 'workaround' makes sense, as in its probably a better practice than anything else - what if there where two camera apps installed and they needed two slightly different intents, or you wanted to A/B test, or it was running on a tablet with no front camera. All this can be handled by `CameraActivity` and not something the navigation graph could do `magic` to resolve :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. Many thanks @Blundell